# ErrorT binding function

Tags: haskell

```
newtype ErrorT e m a = ErrorT { runErrorT :: m (Either e a) }

instance (Monad m, Error e) => Monad (ErrorT e m) where
m >>= k = ErrorT $ do
    a <- runErrorT m
    case a of
        Left l -> return (Left l)
        Right r -> runErrorT (k r)
```

`ErrorT` is just a value constructor ( type constructor as well) and to get instance of that type ( to get `ErrorT` value ) we have to call constructor with one parameter- a function ( destructor) which gets `ErrorT` and returns inner monad, in our case it is any `m` (Either e a). So,  in bind function it is defined: `m >>= k = ErrorT $ ...`. But, in its definion it calls `runErrorT` which is just definied. So something like recursive call. But, I suppose that there is no recursion here. That means that I misunderstand something with monad/ monad transformers. Please help :)

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused by the `newtype` wrapper. The newtype definition of `ErrorT` results in two functions being defined:

```
ErrorT :: m (Either e a) -> ErrorT e m a
runErrorT :: ErrorT e m a -> m (Either e a)
```

so in the definition of `(>>=)`, `ErrorT $ do ...` refers to the constructor for the `ErrorT` newtype while

```
a <- runErrorT m
runErrorT (k r)
```

refer to the 'unwrapping' function to extract the underlying `m (Either e a)`.